# Distributed Tensorflow with model parallelism and nodes storing variables

Tags: tensorflow

Imagining the following scenario where I have a model computation graph so big that does not fit into a single machine. Therefore, I want to split the computation graph between two machines. Additionally, I want the machines who make the computation to store also the variables they modify/read (I don't want to set extra Parameter Servers and I am assuming the set of variables accessed by model graph partitions is disjoint).

Could you provide a example where I can achieve this configuration using Distributed Tensorflow, for example with the primitive `tf.device()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the explanation on the tensorflow site (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).

Use `tf.device('/job:worker/task:1')` to place nodes on one machine or another. You can place them as you want, just pay attention that the inputs that are placed on a different machine will require the data to be send over the network.

As far as I know you can't get rid of parameter servers. A parameter server is just a job that handles variable updates. There's nothing to stop you from running the job on the same machine as tensorflow. So your setup is that you start the tensorflow on the two machines and place on each machine a parameter server. Just make sure that the variables are placed on the local parameter server (again with tf.device).